# Need to optimize the insert query in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I am using following code to insert multiple records into a table. As you can see the query is in a loop. Every time the loop executes, seperate sql query is run to insert it.

I want a approach where instead of running multiple queries, only single INSERT sql query should run with multiple insert statements.

Though this code of mine is functioning perfectly but I need to optimize it.

```
$managed_ailments = unserialize($ailments);
foreach($managed_ailments as $ailment_id)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PATIENTS_AILMENTS_RECORDS ."";
    $sql .= "(patient_id, ailment_id, datecreated) VALUES";
    $sql .= "($patient_id, $ailment_id, now())";
    $query = $mysql->query($sql);
}
```

Here $managed_ailments is a serialized array which i have unserialized. There can be one or more than one values in the array. $mysql->query($sql) is my custom function.

Please help me to convert this code into a single sql query which does it all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of `.""` at the end of the 4th line?  You're appending an empty string.

Comment: @awm I'm thinking the intention was a space.

Comment: @njk I'm thinking you're probably right.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing any SQL escaping here. This is terrifying.

Comment: Using batched inserts as a couple of the respondents suggest is a good idea as a batchsize of 10, say, reduces the table locks and SQL RPCs by ten-fold.  Going to 100x isn't really worth it.  Ditto Motjaba's suggestion of using prepared statements.  If you are doing, say, 50+ inserts at a go then it might be worth doing and outer loop 0,10,20,... processing batches of 10 using a prepared statement and a second close-outloop doing the last 1-9 if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$managed_ailments = unserialize($ailments);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PATIENTS_AILMENTS_RECORDS ."";
$sql .= "(patient_id, ailment_id, datecreated) VALUES (";

$query_parts = array();

foreach($managed_ailments as $ailment_id) {
    $query_parts[] = "($patient_id, $ailment_id, now()";
}
$sql .= implode(",", $query_parts);
$sql .= ")";

$query = $mysql->query($sql);
```

Comment: what happens if `$ailments` is large enough that your `$sql` is larger than the maximum allowed packet on the target system?

Comment: @TerryE I'm not sure, I'm not aware of any such max packet size in MySQL, unless you mean the network packets.  In the latter case it shouldn't matter.  If there is a max query length for MySQL, you'd just have to find some way to break the query up and only insert X records at once.

Comment: See [Packet too large](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html).  This is _typically_ 16Mb.  But its a constraint and some time you might hit it -- and then your code will fail silently.   There is another issue here -- that if you are updating 10K rows, say, then the table (if MyISAM) will be locked for quite a long time, and any other requests wanting the table will stall.

Comment: @TerryE - In my case the table is very small, say less than 200 records, so it wont be of any worry to me

Answer (score 2):

you can add a value statement for each recordthen exectute the query, i.e:

```
INSERT INTO example 
    (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
    (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
    (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
    (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
    (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQLi extension which has prepared statement. You will send the template once to the server then withen a loop you just send data.

```
//initialize and connect $mysqli via MySQLi extension 


$sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PATIENTS_AILMENTS_RECORDS ."";
$sql .= "(patient_id, ailment_id, datecreated) VALUES";
$sql .= "(?, ?, now())";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)

$managed_ailments = unserialize($ailments);
foreach($managed_ailments as $ailment_id) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $patient_id, $ailment_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Note that I'm assuming both $patient_id, $ailment_id are integers. And also assuming you don't want to keep the results of executed queries, because you are overwriting the     $query

This will reduce the overhead of NOW() function and save some bandwidth.

Here is a link to [PHP MySQLi Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)